# Getting an error when calling functions inside a while loop in C++

Tags: c++, string, loops, while-loop

I am sorry in advance if this is a duplicate. I've tried to find a problem that is similar but did not get a solution. I get the following error: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string" when I ask the user if they would like to enter again. The program ends if you enter 'N' but when you enter 'Y', it gives me the error above. My program asks for user a date in format: (December 25th, 2019) and it converts it to format: (MM/DD/YYYY). The code works but I am just encountering one error when I am looping it.

Heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void getDate(string &mdy){
    cout<<"Enter Any Date in Format: (December 25th, 2019) ";
    getline(cin, mdy);
}
void extract (string &mdy, string &m, string &d, string &y){
    int startIndex, endIndex, endIndexDay, startIndexDay, startIndexYear, endIndexYear;

    startIndex = 0;
    endIndex = mdy.find(' ');
    startIndexDay = ((endIndex - startIndex) +1);
    endIndexDay = mdy.find(',');
    startIndexYear = (endIndexDay +2);
    endIndexYear = mdy.find(' ');

    m = mdy.substr(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
    d = mdy.substr(startIndexDay, (endIndexDay - startIndexDay) - 2);
    y = mdy.substr(startIndexYear, endIndexYear - startIndexYear);
}
void convertDigits(string &mdy, string &d, string &y, int &dInt, int &yInt){
    dInt = stoi(d);
    yInt = stoi(y);
}
void convertMonths(string &mdy, string &m, int &mInt, int &dInt, int &yInt){

    if (m == "january" || m == "January")
        mInt = 1;
    else if (m == "febraury" || m == "February")
        mInt = 2;
    else if (m == "march" || m == "March")
        mInt = 3;
    else if (m == "april" || m == "April")
        mInt = 4;
    else if (m == "may" || m == "May")
        mInt = 5;
    else if (m == "june" || m == "June")
        mInt = 6;
    else if (m == "july" || m == "July")
        mInt = 7;
    else if (m == "august" || m == "August")
        mInt = 8;
    else if (m == "september" || m == "September")
        mInt = 9;
    else if (m == "october" || m == "October")
        mInt = 10;
    else if (m == "november" || m == "November")
        mInt = 11;
    else if (m == "december" || m == "December")
        mInt = 12;
    else
        cerr<<"Error...Please check your spelling and the date format and try again.";

    cout<<endl<<"Another Date Format is: "<<dInt<<"/"<<mInt<<"/"<<yInt<<endl;   //Outputting the new date.
}
int main() {
    string date, month, day, year;
    int monthInt, dayInt, yearInt;
    char tryAgain = 'Y';

    while (tryAgain =='Y' || tryAgain == 'y'){

        getDate(date);
        extract(date, month, day, year);
        convertDigits(date, day, year, dayInt, yearInt);
        convertMonths(date, month, monthInt, dayInt, yearInt);

        cout<<"Try Again? Type Y or N: ";
        cin>>tryAgain;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works for me .. What compiler is this?

Comment: I am using cLion

Comment: CLion isn't a compiler, it's an IDE... I assume you are using gcc/g++ .. and in that case the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, sorry the compiler I am using is gcc or g++

Comment: `std::out_of_range: basic_string` means, you are accessing characters behind end of a `std::string`. Not sure where it happens but: Mixing stream input `>>` and `std::getline()` needs some extra caution. Hence, I would debug and check for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `getline` after `cin >>`  you need to flush the **newline** out of the buffer in between.

Add `cin.ignore()` to getDate() function

```cpp
void getDate(string &mdy){
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Enter Any Date in Format: (December 25th, 2019) ";
    getline(cin, mdy);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked when I used cin.ignore(100, '\n') inside the while loop under the line of if they want to try again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors that prevent the posted code to work as expected.

As already noted, `std::cin` leaves any newline in the input stream, so that a subsequent call to `std::getline` would result in an empty string. You could simply skip every input line containing only newlines

```
while ( getline(cin, mdy)  &&  mdy.empty() )
    ;
```

Another issue is in the `extract` function, where there are multiple calls to [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) without specifing a starting position (which is always implicitly set to 0):

```
int endIndex, startIndexYear, endIndexYear;
// ...
endIndex = mdy.find(' ');
// ...
endIndexYear = mdy.find(' '); // --> endIndexYear is equal to endIndex

y = mdy.substr(startIndexYear, endIndexYear - startIndexYear);
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This becomes negative.
// It seems to "work" because when converted to an unsigned type, it is interpreted
// as a big number, greater than the size of the string, and then clamped to that size.
```

When the searched character isn't found (pretty much what's to be expected passing an empty string), `find` returns [`std::string::npos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos), defined as

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```

Where `size_type` is an unsigned type. So when an empty string is passed to this function, this is what happens

```
startIndex = 0;
endIndex = mdy.find(' ');                        // --> -1
startIndexDay = ((endIndex - startIndex) +1);    // -->  0
endIndexDay = mdy.find(',');                     // --> -1  
startIndexYear = (endIndexDay +2);               // -->  1
endIndexYear = mdy.find(' ');                    // --> -1 

m = mdy.substr(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);                 // --> ""
d = mdy.substr(startIndexDay, (endIndexDay - startIndexDay) - 2);  // --> ""
y = mdy.substr(startIndexYear, endIndexYear - startIndexYear);
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mdy[1] is out of bounds, so it throws an exception
```

It would be much easier to use [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to exctract those tokens and form the converted date.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string convert_date(std::string const& mdy)
{
    std::string s_month;
    std::string s_day;
    int year;

    std::istringstream iss{mdy};

    iss >> s_month >> s_day >> year;
    if ( !iss )
    {
        // Wrong format, deal with the error as you prefer
        return "";
    }

    // Convert a string to the corresponding month number. To be implemented.
    // E.g. "Jannuary" -> 1
    int month = get_month_num(s_month);

    // It extracts only the numbers, ignoring trailing "st," or "th,"
    int day = std::stoi(s_day);

    // Here you could validate those numbers, e.g. rejecting a day greater than 31

    // Now compose the converted string "MM/DD/YYYY"
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << month << '/'
        << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << day << '/' << year;
    return oss.str();
}
```